# php photo -> invalid request

Tags: php, facebook, request, photo

hi first sorry for my english.

I want show profil photo, so I do :

```
<?php

  try {

    $fql = "select cover_object_id from album where type='profile' and owner = $user";
$param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql,
 'callback'  => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
   }

$coverpid=$fqlResult[0]['cover_object_id'];

  try {

    $fql = "select src_big from photo where object_id=$coverpid";
$param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql,
 'callback'  => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
   }

$url_photo=$fqlResult[0]['src_big'];
echo '<img src="' . $url_photo . '">';

$bdd->exec("UPDATE user SET url_photo = '$url_photo'  WHERE user_id = '$user'");

?>
```

I can show photo, then for show photo again and reduce api request number, i record photo's url in my database. But problem : the url give me an ivalid request.

How proceed ? I think i need add an access token in the url but i dont know how obtain that...

Can you help me ? Thanks a lot.

PS : I have user_photos permission